# Why global variable inside for loop doesn't change value? Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, variables, global

I have a problem when executing a function that runs a for loop with 3 global variables that will be passed to a callback function. All the arrays have the same length, the problem comes with the 3 window variables, called in `getPickup()` inside the callback function don't change value in any of the loop goes. I find it strange because those variables should get a new value updated from `location` when the callback function is finished, and the loop is run again.

```
function calculateDistanceDriverCustomer() {
       {% autoescape off %}
       var locations = {{ locations }}
       {% endautoescape %}

       {% autoescape off %}
       var firstname = {{ firstname }}
       {% endautoescape %}

       {% autoescape off %}
       var lastname = {{ lastname }}
       {% endautoescape %}

       {% autoescape off %}
       var rating = {{ rating }}
       {% endautoescape %}
       var location;
       for (location = 0; location < locations.length; location++) {
        var origin = locations[location];
        window.firstname = firstname[location];
        window.lastname = lastname[location];
        window.rating = rating[location];
        var destination = $('#origin-input').val();
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
                {
                    origins: [origin],
                    destinations: [destination],
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC, // kilometers and meters.
                    avoidHighways: false,
                    avoidTolls: false
                }, callback);
        }
};
```

```
function callback(response, status) {
            if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                $('#result').html(err);
            } else {
                var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
                var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
                if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                    $('#result').html("Better get on a plane. There are no roads between "  + origin + " and " + destination);
                } else {
                        //get estimated pickup time if distance less or equal than 10km
                    function getPickup() {
                        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
                        var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration;
                        var distance_in_kilo = distance.value / 1000;
                        var duration_value = duration.value*1000;
                        console.log(distance_in_kilo);
                        var time = new Date()
                        time = new Date(time.getTime() + duration_value);
                        var date = new Date(time)
                        var currenthr = date.getHours()
                        var currentmin = date.getMinutes()
                        var currentsec = date.getSeconds()
                        if (currenthr   < 10) {currenthr   = "0"+currenthr;}
                        if (currentmin < 10) {currentmin = "0"+currentmin;}
                        if (currentsec < 10) {currentsec = "0"+currentsec;}
                        window.pickupTime = currenthr + ":" + currentmin + ":" + currentsec;
                        console.log(pickupTime);
                        if (distance_in_kilo <= 3000) {
                            var name = document.createElement("hd");
                            var brk = document.createElement("br");
                            var node = document.createTextNode(window.firstname + " " + 
                            window.lastname);
                            name.appendChild(node);
                            var element = document.getElementById("cars");
                            element.appendChild(name);
                            element.appendChild(brk);
                            var pickup = document.createElement("hd");
                            var node1 = document.createTextNode("Pickup Time: " + window.pickupTime);
                            pickup.appendChild(node1);
                            var element1 = document.getElementById("cars");
                            element1.appendChild(pickup);
                            element1.appendChild(brk);
                            var rating = document.createElement("hd");
                            var node3 = document.createTextNode("rating: " + window.rating);
                            rating.appendChild(node3);
                            var element3 = document.getElementById("cars");
                            element3.appendChild(rating);
                            element3.appendChild(brk);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Not available");
                        }

                     }
                    getPickup();
                }
            }
        };
```

The variables are defined at the beginning of the for loop, they are `window.firstname`,`window.lastname` and `window.rating`. They get the value from an array whose contents have been passed from python(defined at beginning of `calculateDistanceDriverCustomer()`.
This is the python code:

```
 cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute("SELECT CurrentLocation, FirstName, LastName, OverallRating FROM driver WHERE OnJourney=0")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()  # data from database
    locations = []
    firstname = []
    lastname = []
    rating = []
    for row in rows:
        locations.append(row['CurrentLocation'])
        firstname.append(row['FirstName'])
        lastname.append(row['LastName'])
        rating.append(row['OverallRating'])
    return render_template("Search.html", rows=rows, locations=locations, firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, rating=rating)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you post full code so we can see where variables are defined?

Comment: also every time you call callback function you define  getPickup() function all over again. You should define it elsewhere one time and call it from callback function.

Comment: I've just edited it @mandza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no knowledge of Django, but the `getDistanceMatrix` callback call is probably made asynchronously. This means that your for-loop is already finished when the first callback is triggered. Resulting in all callbacks using the values `window.firstname`, `window.lastname` and `window.rating` that are **set by the last iteration** of the loop.

If this is indeed the issue you can resolve it by passing them as `callback` parameters instead.

```
for (let location = 0; location < locations.length; location++) {
  // ^^^ Move the location definition inside the for-loop and use `let` instead
  //     of `var`. This has to do with scoping and might prevent bugs later on.               
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

  // Use `const` (or `let`) instead of `var` see link above.
  const data        = {},
        destination = $('#origin-input').val(),
        service     = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

  data.origin    = locations[location];
  data.firstname = firstname[location];
  data.lastname  = lastname[location];
  data.rating    = rating[location];

  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins:       [origin],
      destinations:  [destination],
      travelMode:    google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem:    google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC, // kilometers and meters.
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls:    false
    },
    // forward the response and status to the callback and add your data
    (response, status) => callback(response, status, data)
  );
}
```

Then accept those parameters in in your callback:

```
function callback(response, status, data) {
  // ...
  var node = document.createTextNode(`${data.firstname} ${data.lastname}`);
  // ...
}
```

---

I would also recommend to move things like `new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()` and `$('#origin-input').val()` outside of the for-loop. They don't depend upon the elements being iterated and are created more that needed. (If `locations` contains 100 elements you create 100 `new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()` while you most likely only need 1.) I left this out from the example code, since it isn't necessary to fix your code.